# Can't unhide filename extensions

Tags: finder

I have a folder containing a bunch of jpeg files and currently all of the filename extensions (.jpg) are hidden.  How can I unhide all the extensions in this folder?

When I do a "Get Info" on any individual file, I can see that the "Hide extension" checkbox is checked but it's grayed out (i.e. disabled) so I can't change it.  I've gone to Finder's Advanced Preferences and checked "Show all filename extensions" but that hasn't made a difference.  Also, I do have read and write privileges on the files. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research I found the answer.  You have to run this command:

```
SetFile -a e <filename>
```

In effect, this says "Set the file extension attribute (-a e) so that the extension is not hidden.  If the extension were not hidden and you wanted to hide it, you would substitute "E" for "e".

To see all of a file's attributes, run this command:

```
GetFileInfo <filename>
```

A description of all the attributes can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/SetFile.1.html).

Comment: That is nice. Can you also explain how it happened in first place?

Comment: I don't know how it happened.

Comment: For anyone else that faces this issue, as in my case, I had what I thought was a .webloc file, but apparently, I had some sort of URL saved as a file (in the Finder) that was something other than a .webloc (or textClipping?). So I just went to the URL and created a .webloc. I needed the extension for a script I was writing to work.